# How to get any new process start and stop in OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, operating-system

I want to perform some operations in my application when any **new listed process starts or stops in Windows OS.**

I read `subprocess` module, but didn't get a clue.

Can any one knows which method is called when new process is started, or how I can override which `os` module method to achieve my goal.

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: As far as I know, Python doesn't come with any built-in modules to this this. That said, you may be able to use the `ctypes` module to make calls more or less directly to Windows' lower-level C-compatible API. Alternatively, there may be an existing third-party module (like [PyWin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)) that has something in it you could use.

Comment: The Windows kernel is instrumented via WMI. You want the [wmi module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html). See the tutorial for an example of watching for process creation or deletion.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to store all the processes at the beginning of the program using some sort of Array.  Have a thread that constantly checks for changes inside the array.  If it detects a change send "an interrupt" into the main process.

Comment: How will it send an "interrupt" to the main process?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this.  You can either have a boolean which the program constantly polls to check for changes, you can run the sub-routine inside the thread itself or you can have some sort of event listener (https://emptypage.jp/notes/pyevent.en.html)

Comment: no it's not like that, i don't want to monitor this processes by external method. I want to inherit existing OS method to monitor this process, but the problem is i don't know which method i have to inherit for this.